# Hidden Input Elements in Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, fckeditor

I'm having troubles with fckeditor in Firefox.  When the user goes to a page, the html (encoded) is stored in a hidden input element.  I call the predefined fckeditor javascript event to populate my editor with the html from the hidden ContentBody element.

```
        function FCKeditor_OnComplete( editorInstance )
        {
            editorInstance.InsertHtml("");
            var sample = document.getElementById("ContentBody").value;
            editorInstance.InsertHtml(sample);
        }
```

This automatically populates the editor with the desired text in IE, but in Firefox it doesn't.  Firebug gives me the error :

> A is null [Break on this error] var
>   FCKW3CRange=function(A){this._Docume...eateFromRange(this._Document,this);}};\r\n

Using Firebug I can determine that the event method FCKeditor_OnComplete() just isn't fired when using Firefox.  It is, however, in IE.  Any ideas on how to get this to work in both browsers?

The HTML for ContentBody is: 
`<input type="hidden" name="ContentBody" id="ContentBody" value="<%=Model.Article%>" />`

Comment: please, write the HTML code for "ContentBody"

Comment: How do you instantiate the editor? I mean, are you sure that "new FCKeditor" is only executed after the whole document is loaded?

Comment: Yes I am sure. The following executes successfully in both IE and FF: 
window.onload = function() { var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor( 'content' ) ; oFCKeditor.BasePath = "/Content/Javascript/fckeditor/" ; oFCKeditor.Height = 300; oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea() ; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution to this last month while working on a new project.  First I store the encoded HTML string in a hidden input element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ContentBody" id="ContentBody" value="<%=Model.Body%>" />
```

This function is the event that is called when the FCKeditor instance in finished loading.

```
function FCKeditor_OnComplete(editorInstance) 
{
    var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(editorInstance.Name);
    var content = parent.document.getElementById("ContentBody").value;
    var EditedContent = content.replace(/\u201C/g, '"');
    oEditor.InsertHtml(EditedContent);
    content = null;
}
```

It seems Firefox requires the javascript to call parent.document.getElementById()

Answer (score 1):

That is interesting. I never used FCKeditorOnComplete (I had to remove underscore to make WMD happy), but it looks like a good hook. Did you try to put a break point this the FCKEditor function below? Do you arrive there with Firefox? Maybe it is something to do with where your FCKeditorOnComplete is physically situated...

```
function WaitForActive( editorInstance, newStatus )
267...{
268    if ( newStatus == FCK_STATUS_ACTIVE )
269    ...{
270        if ( FCKBrowserInfo.IsGecko )
271            FCKTools.RunFunction( window.onresize ) ;
272
273        _AttachFormSubmitToAPI() ;
274
275        FCK.SetStatus( FCK_STATUS_COMPLETE ) ;
276
277        // Call the special "FCKeditor_OnComplete" function that should be present in
278        // the HTML page where the editor is located.
279        if ( typeof( window.parent.FCKeditor_OnComplete ) == 'function' )
280            window.parent.FCKeditor_OnComplete( FCK ) ;
281    }
282}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your tag has the attribute id="ContentBody"? It's possible to use the attribute name="ContentBody", and IE will (technically incorrectly) interpret that as the ID attribute for getElementById. Firefox will only find it if you use id correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you break on the error and walk up the stack, why is A not set? Or, break on

`document.getElementById("ContentBody").value`

and walk down the stack, looking for a more specific cause.

Comment: In the question, I provided the error that Firebug gives me.  "Firebug gives me the error...."

Comment: Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Ah. So you're saying `document.getElementById("ContentBody").value` is NULL in `FCKeditor_OnComplete` ?

Comment: I'm confused. You said in your earlier comment that it appeared `FCKeditor_OnComplete` was being called too early. Now you're saying you don;t think it's called at all?